# Updating variables in dart changes both data

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I change the value of list2 without changing the value of list1. Changing list2 data updates list1 data.

```
var list = [1,2,3];

var list1;
var list2;

list1 = list;
list2 = list;

list2[0] = 100;  

print(list1); //output [100, 2, 3] // need this to be [1,2,3]
print(list2); //output [100, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Objects are passed by reference. When you do `list1 = list;` and `list2 = list;`, you're assigning the reference of `list` to both `list1` and `list2`. So changing the object at that reference will change the data you see at all of these different variables.

If you want these objects to be modified separately, you need to create a new `List` instance. This can be done with either `List.of` or a `List` literal with the spread operator.

```dart
list2 = List.of(list);
```

or

```dart
list2 = [...list];
```

---

If you only do this for `list2`, both `list1` and `list` will still be the same, even if you change only one.

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3];

var list1;
var list2;

list1 = list;
list2 = [...list];

list2[0] = 100;

list1[0] = 200;//list1 is changed here
//But `list` will be changed as well as shown below
print(list); //output [200,2,3]
print(list1); //output [200,2,3]
print(list2); //output [100,2,3]
```

If you want each of these `List`s to be completely separate, you would need to use `List.of` or a `List` literal with spread for both `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: If you're copying a list, you should always prefer `List.of` (or `[...list]` or `list.toList()`) over `List.from` since `.from` would add unnecessary runtime checks.

Comment: Also note that unlike `List.of`,  `List.from` (without an explicit type) creates a `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Ah didn't think of that, thanks. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `List.of` constructor to assign all `elements` of `list` to `list2`.

Added an example:

```dart
 var list = [1, 2, 3];

var list1;
var list2;

list1 = list;
// use List.of
list2 = List.of(list1);

list2[0] = 100;
print(
list1); //output [1,2,3]
print(list2); //output [100,2,3]
```

Comment: See my comments to [Christopher Moore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63836467/179715): Prefer `List.of` over `List.from`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights @jamesdlin. Edited the answer.